# Htaccess remove query string & redirect to product

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I try to remove/redirect the query string from this link:

http://www.myDomain.com/detail/link-526.html?fb_action_ids=10151931158951677&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

To get this link: http://www.myDomain.com/detail/link-526.html

Any help would be highly appreciate, thanks.

Comment: Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175400/htaccess-redirect-based-on-query-string-and-remove-query-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fb_action_ids=
RewriteRule ^/?detail/link- %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Note that this redirects the browser if there's facebook query string stuff without any of it, but if the content of your page keeps adding it, the redirecting might loop.